# Does robot_localization pakcage requires inter-sensor extrinisic parameteres to be known?

Tags: navigation, calibration, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Just two short question

1. Does this package requires inter-sensor extrinisic parameteres to be known?
2. Does it requires synchronous sensors? My camera works at 20fps but my IMU works at 100

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270592/does-robot_localization-pakcage-requires-inter-sensor-extrinisic-parameteres-to-be-known?/) by [ZanaZak](https://answers.ros.org/users/30251/zanazak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2017-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. The state estimation nodes have no concept of sensor parameters. It also has no concept of inter-sensor relationships. It assumes that your sensor outputs one of the [supported message types](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/robot_localization/html/index.html), and that those sensor messages conform to [ROS standards](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html).
2. No. One of the key features of the package is that it can support an arbitrary number of sensors with varying frequencies.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2017-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZanaZak](https://answers.ros.org/users/30251/zanazak/) on 2017-09-11**:
Thanks for explanations. That's really cool. Just one more question:

Can it also handle the case of reltive scale measurements? I use a mono camera as a pose estimator but translational parts of output message don't have absolute scale

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2017-09-11**:
So every pose message from the sensor is a relative pose to some previous frame? Sadly, this is not yet supported. However, you can (a) change the pose estimator node to produce a velocity instead, or (b) let the pose estimator integrate those relative measurements, and feed that to the filter.